# Formatted text in textarea

Tags: php, javascript

If I have a string

```
<b>This Is In Bold Letters</b>
```

then how can I include in a `<textarea>` so that the string appears in **BOLD** letters, using javascript & PHP?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with a standard html textarea.

There are ways to do it, though:

http://ckeditor.com

http://www.webwiz.co.uk/webwizrichtexteditor/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to your problem is via CSS. Let me give you an example.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Solution</title>
<style>
.boldText {
 font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<textarea>No CSS</textarea>
<textarea class="boldText">With CSS</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If everything was supposed to be bold, this would work.  That is highly unlikely, however.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an WYSIWYG editor, or implement a solution like here in stackoverflow: a textarea to write and a div to preview formatted text.